# python3 django apache on debian mint

Tags: django, apache, debian, python-3.5

Seems like I can not get this to work. An "Internal Server Error" shows on my screen when I visit the URL. My tools are python 3.5.1, apache 2.2 and django 1.8.7

This is my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/people/people/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/people:/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Alias /static/ /var/www/people/static/

<Directory /var/www/people/people>
<Files wsgi.py>
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/people/static>
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This is my wsgi.py

```
"""
WSGI config for people project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "people.settings")
# os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "people.settings"

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is the error in my apache log

```
mod_wsgi (pid=2732): Target WSGI script '/var/www/people/people/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.,
mod_wsgi (pid=2732): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/people/people/wsgi.py'.,
Traceback (most recent call last):,
  File "/var/www/people/people/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>,
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>,
    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>,
    from django import http,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>,
    from django.http.response import (,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 13, in <module>,
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>,
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 6, in <module>,
    from django.db import models,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>,
    from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch  # NOQA,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 16, in <module>,
    from django.db.models import sql,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>,
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *  # NOQA,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 9, in <module>,
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 17, in <module>,
    from django.db.models.aggregates import Count,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/aggregates.py", line 5, in <module>,
    from django.db.models.expressions import Func, Star,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 7, in <module>,
    from django.db.models import fields,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>,
    import uuid,
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.5.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages/uuid.py", line 138,
    if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:,
                                ^,
SyntaxError: invalid syntax,
```

Comment: I've removed the requirements.txt from your question since I don't think thats part of the issue, if others do they may find them in the edit history. It looks like there is an erroneous comma in your code to me

Comment: Can you run the application locally using `./manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @JasonEstibeiro, yes I can however that is not what I want.. I want it to run on a virtual host server at people.manship.com

Answer (score 1):

The uuid library you have installed is not compatible with Python 3.

However there is no need for it, as Python has included a uuid module - in fact an upgraded version of the same package - in the standard library since Python 2.5. Uninstall that library and remove it from your requirements.txt.

Comment: Removed and still not working. I get the feeling that it is trying to read a python3.2 version